react-native-safe-area-context - 'react/renderer/components/view/ViewEventEmitter.h' file not found
i ahve instlled  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.11.1", in a fresh react-native project but gettinng this isssue.
fatal error: 'react/renderer/components/view/ViewEventEmitter.h' file not found
#include <react/renderer/components/view/ViewEventEmitter.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~fatal error: 'react/renderer/components/view/ViewEventEmitter.h' file not found
#include <react/renderer/components/view/ViewEventEmitter.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Here is the detals descriptionn of the issue
/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android24 --sysroot=/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -Dreact_codegen_safeareacontext_EXPORTS -I/Users/apple/repos/PhotosContacts/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/jni/. -I/Users/apple/repos/PhotosContacts/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/jni/../../../../common/cpp -I/Users/apple/repos/PhotosContacts/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/jni/../../../build/generated/source/codegen/jni -I/Users/apple/repos/PhotosContacts/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/jni/../../../build/generated/source/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/safeareacontext -isystem /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/eb4b98dea289284ca2b26e9265bd49ab/transformed/fbjni-0.6.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include -isystem /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/2fa3c78e855de2c4ef8aa6911c4216a0/transformed/react-android-0.76.0-debug/prefab/modules/jsi/include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++20 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wno-gnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments -DLOG_TAG=\"ReactNative\" -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP=1 -DFOLLY_CFG_NO_COROUTINES=1 -DFOLLY_MOBILE=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_RECVMMSG=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_XSI_STRERROR_R=1 -MD -MT safeareacontext_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_safeareacontext.dir/Users/apple/repos/PhotosContacts/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/build/generated/source/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/safeareacontext/EventEmitters.cpp.o -MF safeareacontext_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_safeareacontext.dir/Users/apple/repos/PhotosContacts/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/build/generated/source/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/safeareacontext/EventEmitters.cpp.o.d -o safeareacontext_autolinked_build/CMakeFiles/react_codegen_safeareacontext.dir/Users/apple/repos/PhotosContacts/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/build/generated/source/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/safeareacontext/EventEmitters.cpp.o -c /Users/apple/repos/PhotosContacts/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/build/generated/source/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/safeareacontext/EventEmitters.cpp

In file included from /Users/apple/repos/PhotosContacts/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/build/generated/source/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/safeareacontext/EventEmitters.cpp:11:
/Users/apple/repos/PhotosContacts/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/jni/../../../build/generated/source/codegen/jni/react/renderer/components/safeareacontext/EventEmitters.h:12:10: fatal error: 'react/renderer/components/view/ViewEventEmitter.h' file not found
#include <react/renderer/components/view/ViewEventEmitter.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


I think you need upgrade lastest lib react-native-safe-area-context

on 0.76.3, had to upgrade to the latest version for it to be compiled

I also have the same problem, I'm using the React Native 0.76.0 version and react-native-safe-area-context version is 4.11.1
I removed the react-native-safe-area-context package and it works now.
It's related to the react-native-safe-area-context package. I hope they will fix it.
